# FormData is missing submit's value - get it, maybe without SubmitEvent.submitter?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, form-data

When I listen to a `<form>`'s `submit` event, and get the form's `FormData`, e.g. to submit it via an XHR, the submit button's data is missing:

```html
<form>
  <input type="text" name="x" value="foo" />
  <input type="hidden" name="y" value="bar" />
  <button type="submit" name="submit1" value="bar">submit1</button>
  <input type="submit" name="submit2" value="submit2" />
</form>
```

FormData will have `x` and `y`, but neither `submit1` nor `submit2`. [Try it in a Pen](https://codepen.io/bikubi/pen/vYexxZv). <s>It should</s> I would like it to contain **one of them**, namely the one that triggered the submit -- just like the data that would be sent to `action`.

I could do something `onsubmit`, like

```js
form.onsubmit = function (evt) {
  var fd = new FormData(form);
  fd.append(evt.submitter.name, evt.submitter.value);
  // process fd...
});
```

BUT [SubmitEvent.submitter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SubmitEvent/submitter) is fairly new, notably no IE, and only Safari's TP at the time of writing.

Is there a way to get the submit into FormData without doing a workaround like listening to *all the form's inputs' click events* and creating, say, hidden inputs with their data?

---

After the accepted answer, I did implement a "polyfill":

```js
document.querySelectorAll('form').forEach(function (form) {
  // query might miss <button>s without @type
  form.querySelectorAll('[type="submit"]').forEach(function (submit) {
    submit.addEventListener('click', function () {
      var input = document.createElement('input')
      input.setAttribute('type', 'hidden')
      input.setAttribute('name', this.name)
      input.setAttribute('value', this.value)
      this.form.appendChild(input)
    })
  })
})
```

Comment: @Stalinko -- I think it does, even if the question has a broader scope than mine, I guess that's why I hadn't found it before asking :) Thanks!

Comment: welcome) happy to help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a way to get the submit into FormData without doing a workaround like listening to all the form's inputs' click events and creating, say, hidden inputs with their data?

No.

`SubmitEvent.submitter` is the feature that was added to take away the need for separate click events.